# Using \ifdraft like \iffalse

Tags: draft

Note: I don't think the `ifdraft` package provides exactly what I'm looking for, but it could be wrappered (I just don't know how :-) )

I'd like to do this:

```
\ifdraft
... pgf graph component that's only for me
\fi
```

I'm currently using `\iffalse` and `\fi`, but it's obviously more clunky to change 20 locations instead of one. I'm trying to avoid `\ifdraft{do x}{do y}` because 1) it's uglier and therefore less readable 2) 95% of my use cases would be `\ifdraft{do X}{}`. If there's a way to wrapper `ifdraft{do X}{}` into `\ifdraft X \fi` that would be perfect!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `\newif`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifdraft
\drafttrue % or \draftfalse
\begin{document}
\ifdraft
This is a draft.
\else
This isn't.
\fi
\end{document}
```

The `\else` part can be omitted.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I want to display the Git hash info - from the VC package - when in draft mode and then hide it when switching to final. In my Makefile, I am simply doing the following:

    `.tex.pdf:`
    `pdflatex $<`

Followed by passing in the filename. Could I use something like `make $file-draft` and `make $file-final` to accomplish this?

Comment: @Chris --- I think it would be best to ask a new question about this.

Answer (score 11):

You could change the meaning of `\ifdraft`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{ifdraft}

% save a copy of \ifdfraft
\let\ORIifdraft\ifdraft
% redefine it to be a normal conditional with \else and \fi
% according to the document condition
\ORIifdraft{\let\ifdraft\iftrue}{\let\ifdraft\iffalse}

\begin{document}

\ifdraft
 DRAFT
\fi

Text.

\end{document}
```

Or, better, you can define your own new conditional. This is my recommended way.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{ifdraft}

% define a new conditional with \else and \fi
% according to the document condition
\ifdraft{\let\ifxdraft\iftrue}{\let\ifxdraft\iffalse}

\begin{document}

\ifxdraft
 DRAFT
\fi

Text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own `\ifdraftT` that can be used as `\ifdraftT{do X}` if you will.

Otherwise, a true TeX `if` `\ifdraft` needs to be `\let` to `\iffalse` or `\iftrue` or things could go wrong …

With the [`ifdraft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifdraft) package loaded, you can simply

```
\let\ifdraft\if@draft
```

and `\ifdraft` works as the internal `\if@draft` (which is used by the original `\ifdraft`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\makeatletter
\let\ifdraft\if@draft
\newcommand*{\ifdraftT}{\if@draft\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Foo\par
\ifdraft
  something
\fi

Bar\par
\ifdraftT{something else}

Biba
\end{document}
```