# Print in draft mode, hide in final

Tags: conditionals

**Note**: For context, please see my comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122103/using-ifdraft-like-iffalse/122104?noredirect=1#comment1276804_122104).

I would like to print the Git hash (from the VC package) while in draft mode and hide it when typesetting the final version of a document. I know this is possible in other languages, but don't know what options are availble in TeX. For example, in Ruby I can do the following:

```ruby
if MacOS.version <= :el_capitan
  version '12.1.6'
  sha256  '23b9fc6ef5c03cbcab041566503c556d5baf56b2ec18f551e6f0e9e6b48dc690'
elsif MacOS.version <= :high_sierra
  version '12.6.7'
  sha256 'd0647c864268b187343bd95bfcf490d6a2388579b1f8fce64a289c65341b1144'
else
  version '13.0'
  sha256 '38126aa393fd6cafdc91903bbca50d0555f06f7c0f08161c6ab110206ecaada3'
end
```

I've tried to do this with `ifdraft` but it's rather fiddly. Would `comment` be a more appropriate package to use here?